Scorlling in svg element g-tag
<svg>
  <g id="SA1A">
    <rect id="berthbg-1" data-name="berthbg-1" className="cls-24" x="615.48" y="369.06" width="22.77" height="18" transform="translate(1253.74 756.13) rotate(-180)" />
    <text id="indicator-1" data-name="indicator-1" className="cls-48" transform="translate(616.11 384.25) scale(.83 1)">
      Hello, How to scroll me in this text inside g tag of svg element?
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>

Below is the size of box (svg image).
enter image description here
I tried using overflow and marquee tag but not work and I want this text to scroll inside the attached image box not to overlap outside.

A possible solution would be using a symbol like in the following example.
The symbol has a viewBox limiting the view (you can see only the rect id="berthbg-1")
For the animation I'm using SMIL and I'm animating the x attribute of the text. You may want to choose a different solution.
Since you have it all in the symbol you need to use the symbol with a <use> element.


<svg viewBox="615 368 140 20">
  <symbol viewBox="615.48 369.06 22.77 18" id="SA1A" >
    <rect id="berthbg-1" x="615.48" y="369.06" width="22.77" height="18" transform="translate(1253.74 756.13) rotate(-180)" fill="silver" />
    <text id="indicator" transform="translate(616.11 384.25) scale(.83 1)" x="409" text-anchor="end">
      Hello, How to scroll me in this text inside g tag of svg element?
      
      <animate 
       attributeName="x"
       attributeType="XML"
       from="409" to="0"
       dur="20s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </text>
  </symbol>
  <use href="#SA1A" x="615.48" y="369.06" width="22.77" height="18"/>
</svg>



I've added a viewBox to the SVG element since otherwise everything falls outside the svg canvas.
